# How to have only one app on an android device?

Tags: android

Is there a way to hide all apps installed on the device and make only one app available to the user? In a way that the app automatically starts as soon as the screen is unlocked?

What I basically want to do is to have a device that's dedicated to the use of a single app. Can this somehow be accomplished? What options are available?

Since this app won't be distributed through google play or any other official channel, any even undocumented hacks would be an option. Any advise is welcome.

Comment: Yes duplicate, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I think this can be implemented is by creating an custom launcher and include your app inside that launcher.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.